# _strrev function isnt working inside a function, but works outside

Tags: c, string, reverse

I’m trying to get the `_strrev` function to work but when I put my string into a function it doesn’t seem to work, just when I'm out of the function..
I’m getting so frustrated because I'm not getting anywhere with this..
Here's my code so far

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse(char *string) {
    char *str, temp;
    int begin = 0, end = 0;
    char word[64];
    int jaja = 0;

    printf("Your string from the function is %s\n", string);
    printf("%s\n", _strrev(&string)); //And why isnt this working
    jaja = strlen(string);
    printf("Your string has %d characters\n", jaja);
}
int main()
{
    char *str;
    scanf("%s", &str);
    printf("%s\n", _strrev(&str)); //How come this works

    reverse("Okay");

    getchar();
    return(0);
}
```

So I would love some guidance where my mistake is, I seriously cant find it.

Comment: In what way does it not work?  What is the expected output and what is the output you are seeing?

Comment: @ch3rub7 according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235404.aspx) `strrev` is deprecated and `_strrev` must be used instead

Comment: Im getting all kinds of garbage och letters instead of the string reversed. And thé program crashes.

Comment: Change `&str` to `str` and change `char *str;` to `char str[1000];`. That's not completely safe as `scanf` could still overrun the buffer if you type more than 999 characters, but it should get you started.

Comment: The call `reverse("Okay")` causes undefined behavior because you are not allowed to modify a string literal. To fix that, you can use the string literal to initialize an array of `char` and pass the array to `reverse`. E.g. `char okay[] = "Okay"; reverse(okay);`

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hby7w40.aspx) The prototype for `_strrev` is

```
char *_strrev(
   char *str 
);
```

If you have a `char *string` you must call it like this :

```
printf("%s\n", _strrev(string));
```

In this case

```
printf("%s\n", _strrev(&string));
```

you are passing a `char**`

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you posted in your code comments:

```
int main()
    {
        char *str;
        scanf("%s", &str);
        printf("%s\n", _strrev(&str)); //How come this works
```

That works because you're lucky, as your call to `scanf()` places whatever it reads into the actual memory used for the pointer `str`, and you're not entering enough data to cause problems.  Try entering a really long string when running this program and it won't work as well.

You need to actually have a `char` buffer to read data into, like this:

```
int main()
    {
        char str[256];
        scanf("%s", str);
        printf("%s\n", _strrev(str));
```

or

```
int main()
    {
        char *str = malloc( 256 );
        scanf("%s", str);
        printf("%s\n", _strrev(str));
```

And as pointed out in the comments to the question, you can still overrun your buffer.